# Integrating AngularJS with struts 1.x

Tags: angularjs, struts, struts-1

We have a legacy application using struts 1 and we would like to use angularJS as a front end framework for some pages.
So how to integrate AngularJS within this application ?

Some steps to follow in order to start using angularJS with struts would be heplful.

Thanks

Comment: Return JSON from your actions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use angularjs with struts 1.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306645/how-to-use-angularjs-with-struts-1-x)

Comment: I may understand that Angularjs needs Json objects from struts, but before starting to use Angularjs could you provide some details about the setup, what sort of files we need to configure..  Thanks

Comment: Do you still finding the solution?

Comment: Yes still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Some simple example for AngularJS code given below,

In HTML add the module name and source file,

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="App_Name">
<src="../your_path/angular.min.js"> //Javascript file
```

In Script load the module and use `$http` function call the servlet,

```
angular.module('App_Name', [])
    .controller('App_Controller', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/URL.do').
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         //console.log(data);
         $scope.myVar = data;   //Assign to AngularJS Variable
     }).
     error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         //console.log(data);
     });
}]);
```

Inside body,

```
<body data-ng-controller="App_Controller">..</body>
```

Hope this helps.